# why typescript generic T any not working?

Tags: typescript, generics

The playground [demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-cEVDgGh5U4h4AMGCD2DRvm4zMx2AxmJB+LBoOpEi34HoRF4AEQAUVWDEQNX0k6SOMn4AcqAA5MIAHKQCSToIqADy3zIu0E-a0kGOorIClc0jwycgjZ0oyw+hQCEQMOEVw7CQm2iEQDA4HFuhYNguG4IISiAA)

The diff:

A:

```
function<T extends { status: number }> () {}
```

B:

```
function<T = any> () {}
```

the `B` not access T's property，the `A` only access T's `status`.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's working exactly as it's supposed to.  You cannot access the property `status` of a variable which is type `T` unless you know that `T` has a `status` property.

`<T extends { status: number }>` means that regardless of the specific value of `T`, it will always have a property `status`.

`<T = any>` means that `T` can be anything.  How are you going to access the property `status` of a `boolean`, for example?  That would cause a runtime error.  So typescript gives you a compile time error in order to make sure that you don't do this.

Comment: why `(e as any).status` can working? `e` is `T` type

Comment: When you have a variable which is type `any`, typescript assumes that whatever operation you are doing is ok.  In the case of `<T = any>`, `T` is not always `any` -- that's just the default value.  `T` can be a specific type, based on that value that you set when you call it.  You can do something like this `const f2 = fun2<string>();` where `T` is `string` and your function will only accept strings.

Comment: `e as any` tells typescript to ignore the actual type of `e` and use `any` instead.

Comment: how can i fix it? I hope `e.status` or `e.someProp` can working.

Comment: Is there a specific document address that describes the problem。I can not find